# How to show suggestions from a list of strings fetched as json, under a form in the view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a web application project in which I need to take input from user. But I want the input to be any one from the **list**. As the **list** would be huge so I can not put it in a drop down. 
The **list** can be fetched in **json** format by calling a method in **AdminController**.

This is the method in AdminController that returns json file containing list of strings (courses):

```
public JsonResult gclist() {
        return Json(repObj.clist());
    }
```

Here **reObj.clist()** returns a **list** of **string** type
and **gclist()** returns that list in json format.

This is the form division that takes the input from user:

```
<div class="form-group column">
    <label asp-for="Course" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Course" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course Name" />
</div>
```

How can I make the page fetch the whole list by calling **gclist** as soon as it loads and when the user starts typing in the form, similar suggestions start showing under the form (suggestions of the Courses from the list).

For example:

Suppose list has ['Apple','Banana','Grapes',...]
User enters "a" : first 10 elements starting with or having "a" should show up. As here suggestion will have '**A**pple','B**a**n**a**n**a**','Gr**a**pes'

User continues typing "ap" : first 10 elements starting with or having "ap" should show up. As here suggestions will have '**Ap**ple', 'Gr**ap**e'.

Comment: Perhaps this could get you started? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp  If you're using any UI frameworks in your project it may have something specific built in.  You'll want to take the JSON coming from your API and then `JSON.parse(jsonResult)` it and feed it into your autocomplete.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. But the link you shared only matches initials and is not exactly what I want it to do. I want it to suggest first 10 of all the strings having what is entered by the user.